# Accessing data in an XML using TBXML?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

In my iPhone application, I need to get the data in an xml file.  I'm using TBXML to do that.

Here's the the xml (simplified) that I need to get the data from:

```
<ResultSet version="1.0">
    <Result>
        <woeid>12792023</woeid>
    </Result>
</ResultSet>
```

I need to put the data in `woeid` into an NSString.

I'm still very new to XML, and I'm problably very confused.  Here's how I was trying to access it.

```
//locationString is a NSString containing a URL of a XML file
TBXML * XML = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:locationString]] retain];
TBXMLElement * rootXML = XML.rootXMLElement;
NSString *WOEID = [TBXML textForElement:[TBXML childElementNamed:@"Result" parentElement:rootXML]];
```

It doesn't work correctly, so I'm assuming I'm doing it all wrong.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

The full XML file is here:

```
-<ResultSet version="1.0">
   <Error>0</Error>
   <ErrorMessage>No error</ErrorMessage>
   <Locale>us_US</Locale>
   <Quality>99</Quality>
   <Found>1</Found>
     −<Result>
      <quality>72</quality>
      <latitude>xxxxxxxx</latitude>
      <longitude>xxxxxxxxx</longitude>
      <offsetlat>xxxxxxxx</offsetlat>
      <offsetlon>xxxxxxxxx</offsetlon>
      <radius>500</radius>
      <name>xxxxxxxx,xxxxxxx</name>
      <line1>xxxxx xxx</line1>
      <line2>xxxx, xx  xxxxx</line2>
      <line3/>
      <line4>United States</line4>
      <house/>
      <street>xxxx xxx</street>
      <xstreet/>
      <unittype/>
      <unit/>
      <postal>11111</postal>
      <neighborhood/>
      <city>xxxxxxx</city>
      <county>xxxxxxx</county>
      <state>xxxxxx</state>
      <country>United States</country>
      <countrycode>US</countrycode>
      <statecode>TX</statecode>
      <countycode/>
      <hash/>
      <woeid>11111111</woeid>
      <woetype>11</woetype>
      <uzip>xxxxx</uzip>
   </Result>
</ResultSet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TBXMLElement *rootXML = XML.rootXMLElement;
TBXMLElement *e = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"Result" parentElement:rootXML];
NSString *woeid = [TBXML textForElement:e->firstChild];
```

`childElementNamed` returns the element you name, so in this case "Result". You want the content of the *child* of this element

Comment: It doesn't work as it selects the wrong data.  Let me post the whole XML file for you above in my post, maybe that will help.

Comment: Ok, it looks like your code selects the first child of "Results".  How can I select a different child farther down the list?

Comment: Aha, got it fixed.  Posted it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was similar to Thomas's answer, so I'll leave his as correct because he helped me get here.  Because woeid was nested down in the XML, you have to do this:

```
TBXMLElement *rootXML = XML.rootXMLElement;
TBXMLElement *results = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"Result" parentElement:rootXML];  
TBXMLElement *WOEID = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"woeid" parentElement:results]; 
NSString *woeid = [TBXML textForElement:WOEID];
```